# 115V to 230V converter

Tags: electrical

In the US some air conditioners require 230V outlets. My apartment only has 115V outlets. Is there a way to convert 115V to 230V so AC can run without loss in cooling power?

Comment: *"...so AC can run without loss in cooling power?"* That remark scares me as it looks like you want to plug your 230 equipment into 120V outlet **DON'T!!**

Comment: @oldfart, I don't know what I want. I have zero knowledge about electricity and electrical appliances. That's why I come here to ask.

Comment: If you're going to be buying this AC unit, just buy one which plugs into a normal 115V outlet. Your local Walmart/Lowes/whoever will have them.

Comment: "zero knowledge" is the scary part here... Even if we offer advice here, it still assumes some basic competency surrounding the question.

Comment: `zero knowledge`  ... sounds like a cause for an "apartment building on fire" news story

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is in principle possible to run a 240V load off a 120V supply using a transformer.

However you must understand that transformers can trade off voltage for current but they can't magic power out of thin air. The feed supplying the transformer must cover both the power requirements of the load and the losses in the transformer. Power is proportional to voltage times current (if the power factor was 1 it would be equal to voltage times current).

In other words if a transformer is converting 120V to 240V then the input current will be more than double the output current.

The problem you will run into is if an air conditioner designed for the US market requires 240V then it probablly requires more power than can be supplied by a normal domestic socket.

> I am looking at this unit  [https://www.amazon.com/Frigidaire-FFRH2522R2-Window-Mounted-Room-Conditioner/dp/B00VV2JORQ/ref=sr_1_10?s=home-garden&ie=UTF8&qid=1525402023&sr=1-10&keywords=16000+btu](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00VV2JORQ)
>    https://www.frigidaire.com/Owner-Center/Product-Support--Manuals/?productCode=FFRH2522R2

https://www.frigidaire.com/Owner-Center/Product-Support--Manuals/?productCode=FFRH2522R2 claims that unit takes 11.3 amps, double that and add some overhead for the transformer and you would be looking at around 25 amps from your 120V supply. Regular domestic sockets in the USA are rated at at best 20A and more commonly 15A. Furthremore those are only intermittant ratings.

Sorry but you either need to find a smaller AC unit that will run off a normal doestic socket or you need to get an electrian in.

Answer (score 0):

There are 120V to 220/230 voltage converters. The simplest is a 1:2 transformer. Alternative are modern electronic converters.

Check how many ampere or VA your equipment uses. It should be on a label next to the voltage. Then chose a transformer or converter which preferable a bit more ampere or VA then that.

If you have the ampere or VA a good electronics shop should know what to sell you.

*Whatever: do not plug your 230V AC into a 120V socket. You have no idea what is inside e.g. there is likely a compressor which may not run on 120V, but still heat up and catch fire.*

Comment: The question explicitly says, "In the US..." Any appliance sold in the US that needs 240V is going to use more power than you can pull from a NEMA 5-20 outlet.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible, depending on how many watts your AC unit uses. What you're looking for is a "110 to 220v transformer".

Here's an example: [https://www.amazon.com/Bright-VC1500W-Voltage-Transformer-converter/dp/B000MXW85A](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000MXW85A)

Make sure your AC is designed for 60hz. If it's meant to be used in the US then it probably is. The transformer will convert the voltage, but it will not change the frequency.

Comment: I am looking at this unit https://www.amazon.com/Frigidaire-FFRH2522R2-Window-Mounted-Room-Conditioner/dp/B00VV2JORQ/ref=sr_1_10?s=home-garden&ie=UTF8&qid=1525402023&sr=1-10&keywords=16000+btu  so you are saying, if I buy this converter and plug it in it it will be safe and work as intended, i.e. not act as a less powerful AC?

Comment: No it won't, I will prepare an answer for you in a minuite.

Comment: Peter is correct, that unit draws too many watts.

Comment: Peter, did you just downvote everybody's answers?

Comment: don't sweat it, you get more points for a controvertial answer than for a boring one :)